# View Property is not available in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

I have a mobile application that is integrated with the firebase, So I need to get the users count in the node js server. So I tried with this tutorial [http://nali.org/google-analytics-v4-api-node-js-starter-example](http://nali.org/google-analytics-v4-api-node-js-starter-example/)

In this tutorial, they use view id, but in my analytics, I view property is not available. How can I get google analytics in node server
[image: My Google Analytics page]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the new Google Analytics for App and Web, which the API doesn't really cover. You are supposed to set up a link to Google BigQuery and get your data from there. The unavoidable [Simo Ahava has an article on the subject](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enable-bigquery-export-google-analytics-app-web/).